# Gmail removing hyperlinks from email. Why?

Tags: python, django, hyperlink, gmail

My application is expected to send email verification link to user.

When I open such an email in Gmail, the links are not shown, Gmail removes them.

If I select [Show original] option, I can see that the links are there.

- Why is it so?
- How can I fix this ?

**Note:** I'm on development server.

**Displayed Email:**

```
Hi from Team!

You just subscribed to our newsletter. Please click the link below in order to confirm:

Thank You!
Team
```

**Original Email:**

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


Hi from Team!

You just subscribed to our newsletter. Please click the link below in order to confirm:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/newsletter/verify_email/MTQ/bmq8o8-15cab7bf32186aab16c2c086e9beaec3/

Thank You!
Team
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should reformat the html file and embed the link in `a` tag

```
<a href="https://www.from.com">from</a>
```

Comment: It won't help. I have two versions of the email "text/plain" and "text/html"

Comment: You were right, I had an error in html link. Thanks! :)